# Nodejs remove top lines of file if longer than a certian length

Tags: node.js, file, logging

> **Note**: there are various similar-looking questions to this, but they aren't for nodejs. Please don't mark this question as a duplicate unless it is a duplicate of a question tagged [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs).
>
> **Note**: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843016) does not answer my question, it explains how to remove x lines from a file, but not to keep x lines from a file. That question does not explain how to get the line length of a file and use that to trim some lines. I answered this question because I found an answer. That answer should clear things up.

In my application, a log file has many lines of logs written to it during normal usage. To save disc space, I would like to remove the first lines of a log file when it is longer than a set amount.

For instance, if the maximum line length is 5 (just for example, not really what I want), then:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

Would get converted to:

```
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
```

And

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
```

Would get converted to:

```
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
```

**Note**: this question is tagged [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs), so I would like an answer in nodejs without any libraries / dependencies (native fs is fine)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove one line from a txt file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843016/how-to-remove-one-line-from-a-txt-file)

Comment: There is no need do reinvent the wheel as long as there are: 'log-rotate' and 'logrotate-stream' modules at npm. I could provide an example of usage if needed.

Comment: Edited to explain how it is not a dup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a partial answer at the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843016/how-to-remove-one-line-from-a-txt-file), but I want to show how it can be adapted to fit my situation:

```
var fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, data){
    if (err){
        throw err;
    }
    var linesCount = data.split("\n").length;
    var wantedLines = data.split("\n").slice(~7+1);//keep 7 lines
    fs.writeFile(filename, wantedLines);
});
```