# Get a Steam key from a txt file then move it to another

Tags: node.js, steam

I'm currently working on a Steam bot project that trades Steam items for Game keys. I'm already done with all the trading part, and the only part missing now is the part where the script actually looks for a key in my txt file. (one key per line)

I have a variable ready called totalKeyWeGive that outputs 1 , 2 , 3 etc depending on how many keys is the user buying.

So now I want to 1. get 1 , 2 , 3 etc keys from my file, then move these used keys to another file.
How can I do that ?

this is the part that I need to modify (everything is working) :

```
offer.accept(offer);
console.log("OFFER ACCEPTED");

//loop on how much we give the key

    //get steamkey from file here ------

}

var textMsg = "Hello ! You bought "+totalKeyWeGive+ " Game keys. Your keys are: "
}

client.chatMessage(offer.partner.getSteamID64(), textMsg);
```

Thanks to everyone who will take the time to read this post. It's kinda messy, sorry about that :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the keys are organized in the txt file, but assuming they are one per line you could do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38843461/4686055

That is, before removing the line, save it in memory and write it to the target file.

Send an interval to slice() to remove multiple lines. Check this out for an example of how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Hope this helps!

**Update**: an alternative approach could be to use the readlines module instead of reading the entire file into memory: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line