# node.js remove a line from .txt file

Tags: node.js, fs, readline

If the line is "removemefromthefile" I want to delete the whole line from the .txt file. How would I do that?
I have the following code:

```
const readline = require('readline');

    var rd = readline.createInterface({
            input: fs.createReadStream('data.txt'),
        });

        rd.on('line', function (line) {
            if (line.trim() === "removemefromthefile") {
                // remove the line
                rd.close()
            }
        })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove one line from a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843016/how-to-remove-one-line-from-a-txt-file)

Comment: Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/remove-line-from-txt-d88v8?file=/src/index.js). Instead of using a stream, I use `fs.readFileSync()`, filter the lines, and write a new file using `fs.writeFileSync()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it,

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('data.txt', { encoding: 'utf-8' }, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw error;
    }

    let dataArray = data.split('\n');

    for (let i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
        if (dataArray[i].trim() === 'removemefromthefile') {
            dataArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    const updatedData = dataArray.join('\n');
    fs.writeFile('data.txt', updatedData, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Successfully updated the file!');
    });
});
```