# Getting error while reading json file using node.js

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I am getting the following error while reading the json file using Node.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

My json file is given below.

> test.json:

```
#PATH:/test/
#DEVICES:div1
#TYPE:p1
{
  name:'Raj',
  address: {
     city:'bbsr'
  }
}
```

This json file has some `#` included strings . Here I need to remove those `#` included string from this file. I am explaining my code below.

```
fs.readdirSync(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads/${fileNameSplit[0]}`).forEach(f => {
        console.log('files', f);
        let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(`${process.env['root_dir']}/uploads/${fileNameSplit[0]}/${f}`);
         let parseData = JSON.parse(rawdata);
         console.log(parseData);
});
```

Here I am trying to read the code first but getting the above error. My need is to remove those `#` included lines from the json file and then read all the data and convert the removed lines to object like `const obj ={PATH:'/test/',DEVICES:'div1',TYPE:p1}`. Here I am using node.js `fs` module to achive this.

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to remove the `#`. you need to do that before trying to parse it with `JSON.parse`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove one line from a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843016/how-to-remove-one-line-from-a-txt-file)

Comment: This is not valid JSON, thus the error. And this is exactly what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @WagnerMattei: I am getting error while reading the file. same I have also mentioned in my post.

Comment: @JeremyThille: NO that is not same post.

Comment: @ChristianBaumann: I know that is not valid json , I want to remove those lines using code.

Comment: ...so you don't want to remove lines from a text file, instead you want to remove lines from a text file?

Comment: my file is a json file.

Comment: And what do you think a JSON file is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, you need to remove those `#` lines from the JSON file. You need to code this yourself. To help with that, read the file into a string and not a Buffer by providing a charset to `readFileSync`.

```
const text = fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8');
console.log(text);
const arr = raw.split("\n");
const noComments = arr.filter(x => x[0] !== "#"));
const filtered = noComments.join("\n");
const data = JSON.parse(filtered);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: But this is not an answer. This is a hint. The answer would be the part of the code you didn't write.

Comment: @Joel : Yes this is a good hint. Can you please complete your code as per my post.

Comment: @JeremyThille Sure, but IMHO that was much more in the spirit of SO. I have added the missing code, but I fear that if OP simply copies the answer, they won't grok it, it would be MUCH better if they had their AB problem solved and could figure it out themselves and learn.

Comment: @subhra_edqart Fine, I added one basic version of the algorithm. Your problem was with the 'utf8'  part, not with the algorithm so try to truly understand all the lines and the logic here instead of just making it work :)

Comment: @JoelPeltonen: what is raw here.

Comment: Ok hopefully its able to delete the # lines but Can I get those deleted lines also ?

Comment: @subhra_edqart I'm sorry, I won't write your entire business logic - what did you try to get the deleted # lines?